# What is the best way to detect anomalous trends in access logs in streaming?

Tags: trend, online-algorithms, anomaly-detection

I just began reading some stuff on the state-of-the-art algorithms to do ML in streaming but I'm fairly new to the field.

I see there's a lot of literature on anomaly detection and regime change detection but all the use-cases are way more complex than the one I need to tackle in the short term.

I have a stream of access logs composed of IP (and I assume I can extract the location from there) and timestamp. What I would like to do is to detect anomalies in the trend of this access to alert a business unit that  "something is happening". Ideally most of these accesses will come from human users interacting with the website, the mobile app or other access points to the infrastructure. The goal then is to identify an abrupt change in the behaviour of the crowd and raise an alert in the matter of minutes.

I would prefer not to use historical data to build the model but rely exclusively on streaming data. Alternatively I could renounce short-term adaptiveness and use historical data to model seasonal trends in a medium-term window (2-3 months).

I'm strongly platform-bound (Flink) so any suggestion should take into account the fact that I will need to implement it in a fully distributed enviroment.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Could you try to edit your question for more details? As for now it is really broad since being about any anomalies in any data...

Comment: I described the data exactly (entries of the form (region,timestamp)) and the kind of anomaly I want to detect (abrupt change in the generating distribution). What kind of information should I add?